# Hashing behavior in Python set

Tags: python, hash, set, subclass

I was trying to understand how sets function internally in Python.

I wrote a subclass of tuple as follows:

```
from random import random
class ball(tuple):
    def __hash__(self):
        a=super().__hash__()%4
        print("hash({0})={1}".format(str(self),a))
        return a
    def __eq__(self,other):
        a=random()>0.5
        print("eq({0},{1})=={2}".format(str(self),str(other),a))
        return a
    def __lt__(self,other):
        print("Called lt({0},{1})".format(str(self),self(other)))
        return super().__hash__(self,other)
```

Then I execute the following code

```
f=[ball([i]) for i in range(5)]
set(f)
```

The output is

```
hash((0,))=3

hash((1,))=2

hash((2,))=1

hash((3,))=0

hash((4,))=3

eq((0,),(4,))==False

eq((0,),(4,))==True

{(3,), (2,), (1,), (0,)}
```

Why does Python check for equality twice in the last situation? This happens quite often.

Update: The output is from Python 3.3. This behavior does not seem to be reproducible in 3.4 onwards.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: on my machine it performs only one check for equality (both if it results in `False` and in `True`).

Comment: @Bakuriu it's randomized, execute several times. Reproduces on my machine

Comment: @J0HN On python3 I already tried to execute that some tens of times and never got that behaviour. However on python2.7 I *can* see the double call (and in that case it's *always* performed).

Comment: @Bakuriu I'm on python 3.3.4. I've replaced `set(f)` with  `print(set(f))` though

Comment: @J0HN And I'm on python 3.4

Comment: Can you try it replacing 5 with something else? I observe that this behavior is not consistent. It seems that it checks twice if the first eq returns False.

Comment: @Bakuriu and this only means that `set` internals have changed between 3.3.4 and 3.4

Comment: @user2154701 on python2 it executes twice in any case.

Comment: I'm on python 3.3.3 BTW.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you see is due to the usage of open addressing in the `set` implementations previous to python3.4 (which uses a combination of open addressing and linear probing, which seems to have "solved" this problem).

First of all in your code both `(0,)` and `(4,)` have the same hash (`3`). When building the `set` the implementation has to check whether an element with the same hash exists or not, and whether it is equal (so that it avoids adding the same element more than once).
This check is perfomed calling the [`set_lookkey`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cf156cfb12e7/Objects/setobject.c#l78) function which is the internal function used by all other code to find elements of a `set`.

In particular (<sup>code a bit simplified to avoid irrelevant details</sup>):

```
i = (size_t)hash & mask;
entry = &table[i];

if (entry->hash == hash) {
    startkey = entry->key;
    Py_INCREF(startkey);
    cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(startkey, key, Py_EQ);
    Py_DECREF(startkey);
    if (cmp < 0)
        return NULL;
    if (table == so->table && entry->key == startkey) {
        if (cmp > 0)
            return entry;
    }
}
```

here you can see that the `set` uses the hash to obtain an index inside the inner table. Then it retrieves the `entry` at that index and checks for equality (`PyObject_RichCompareBool`). If the result (`cmp`) is `< 0` then an error occurred and it returns `NULL`. If `cmp == 0` then it means that the `entry` was *not* equal, when `cmp > 0` (i.e. a true value) then we have found the `entry` which is immediately returned.

In our case `hash = i = 3` and `mask == PySet_MINSIZE - 1 == 7`<sup>1</sup>, so we are taking `entry = &table[3]`.

Note that when `cmp == 0` the execution continues after that block. In this case the `set` tries to check whether there was a collision and thus it checks every entry that is associated with that `hash`. The other entries are found by doing:

```
for (perturb = hash; ; perturb >>= PERTURB_SHIFT) {
        i = (i << 2) + i + perturb + 1;
        entry = &table[i & mask];
```

If we try to compute `i` again we get:

```
(3 << 2) + 3 + 3 + 1 == 19
```

And:

```
19 & 7 == 3
```

In otherwords we are checking the same `entry` again. This explains why `__eq__` is called twice.

All this doesn't happen with python3.4+ because the checks are performed in a different way, which avoids re-checking the same `entry`.

---

Note that all this is an implementation detail. The `set` is free to call `__eq__` how many times he wants, so don't rely on the number of calls to `__eq__`.

Also your `__eq__` method breaks the invariants required from hashable objects: `x == y ==> hash(x) == hash(y)` but in your case this is not always true (see the glossary for [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-hashable)). In other words the instances of your class cannot be safely used with a `set` in a sane way.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is true because `set`s have a minimum size that can store more than 4 elements. `PySet_MINSIZE` is defined in `Include/setobject.h` in the sources.
When creating a new set the `INIT_NONZERO_SET_SLOTS` macro is called which sets the `mask` to `PySet_MINSIZE - 1`. That macro is called by `make_new_set` which is used when building a set from an iterable.